# how to get value of name attribute of a form on click submit button by jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes

First look at my html form layout:

```
<form name="myform">
 <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" />
 <input type="text" name="address" value="" />
 <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to get the value of name attribute (Here, 'myform') while a user clicks on submit button. I am trying to get by following jquery code:

```
$("body").on("click",".sub",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var atr = $(this).parent().attr("name");
  alert (atr);
});
```

But it is not working.

Please note that the form would be dynamic, so I am unable to call it by id or class to get the value of name attribute.

Any idea?

Comment: Please create `jsfiddle` of the problem

Comment: Tushar and Abdullah it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/hkrmt4r3/ Please check in the console. See what error message you get and debug the error.

Comment: Your code works fine for me too http://jsfiddle.net/bj5d5xu9/, maybe you forgot to wrap your code in a `document.ready` function?

Comment: No, I didn't forget to wrap the code in a document.ready function. That was happening for another reason. In my actual form, after <form name="myform">, all others input field was wrap in a table like <table><tr><td>Fullname:</td><td><input type="text" name="fullname" value="" /></td></tr>. So, the parent of input type=submit button was actually the table, not the form. That's why when I called parent it was showing 'undefined'. In my case, it is more suitable to use closest selector.